# Apache and Internal Server error and internal redirects on WordPress install

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess

I am unable to do WordPress installations automatically on my local Apache for the past 4 weeks. The normal process on another machine goes standard - copy the WP install, run and the install script is executed. What I see here is either blank page, or Internal Server Error.

Even if I do correct manually my wp-config.php file with the settings and install, I receive the same error again. The last WP versions are distributed with no .htaccess so I expect no .htaccess to be required on each install for my local server.

Here there are my httpd.conf settings for the directory:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

mod_rewrite is loaded here.

I was suspicious about my /etc/hosts as well, but we have the following:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   localhost.localdomain
```

I had a look in my php.ini file (PHP is 5.3.3), no specific problems. However, my error log from apache states the following:

```
 [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is either a rewrite rule causing an endless rewrite loop or some other kind of alias loop in your config. Without seeing the rest of your apache config I wouldn't be able to tell for sure.

Comment: I don't use virtual hosts, it's a clean install on Apache and that's the root document dir over there. What else could affect?